Payment Gateways not shown when limited to store
I have Commerce Version: 8.x-2.38 installed with Paypal and Stripe. I'm setting these gateways up just fine, and they work, but when I constrain the gateways to appear only with a store, they do not appear at all for products using that store.
Am I missing a setup step? This works just fine on a parallel site.

The answer in my case was store id. I was creating the order items programmatically, and was setting the store ID incorrectly.
Once that was corrected, all good!
